# SOAP/WSDL Web Services in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, soap

I have to develop a SOAP based web service that use WSDL to describe his functionality.
I'm a C/C++ programmer and I'm aware of the existence of SOAP implementations like:

[Apache Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/)  e [Axis2/C](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/c/core/)

but I have difficulty downloading the sources and finding examples and documentation, is it possible that it is no longer supported ?

I would like to find a solution specifically aimed at SOAP requests.

Any personal experience with available solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to Stack Overflow which may be useful: [A Good C++ Library for SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450488/a-good-c-library-for-soap).

The question has been asked 10 years ago and the comments of accepted answer says that Axis is not supported any more and any bug you will face you have to fix it on your own.

Other answers suggested other libraries but I don't know which one could be useful for you.

Please let me know if you found something useful, hope this will help.

Edit:
One of the suggestions was gSOAP. [Here](https://www.genivia.com/dev.html#server-cpp) is the new website link.

It could be just what you are looking for.